# как преобразовать массив JSON в массив объектов

Tags: массивы, json, reactjs

Есть массив json получаемый с помощью fetch

```
{"news":[
{"_id":"2","header":"Заголовок 2","text":"Текст 2"},
{"_id":"1","header":"Заголовок 1","text":"Текст 1"}
]}
```

как его конвертировать в массив вида

```
news[1] = {"_id":"2","header":"Заголовок 2","text":"Текст 2"}
news[0] = {"_id":"1","header":"Заголовок 1","text":"Текст 1"}
```

?

Comment: news[1] и news[0] - порядок именно такой нужен или без разницы?

Comment: без разницы. попробовал этот код выдает ошибку и ругается на reverse (react-dom.development.js:287 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reverse' of undefined)

Comment: Приложите код как Вы запрашиваете данные

Comment: getnews = () => {
        const arr1 = fetch(getNewsUrl,)
            .then(function(response) {
                response.json().then(function (data) {
                    console.log('data',data)
                })
            })
        const arr2 = arr1.news.reverse().map((el) => JSON.stringify(el));
        console.log(arr2[0]);
        console.log(arr2[1]);
    }

Comment: "Cannot read property 'reverse' of undefined" - значит, что у Вас "arr1.news" не определен. Соответственно ошибка ещё раньше, чем обработка JSON. Используйте пару async/await, чтобы дождаться промиса.

Comment: я же ее объявил const arr1 = fetch(getNewsUrl,) .then(function(response) { response.json().then(function (data) { console.log('data',data) }) })     или так объявлять нельзя?

Comment: @БаирБаиров нет, так объявлять нельзя, смотрите мой ответ где `data` это Ваши данные с сервера

Comment: разобрался спасибо. getnews = async () => {
        const arr1 = await fetch(getNews,).then(result => result.json());
        const arr2 = arr1.news.map((el)=>JSON.stringify(el));
        console.log(arr2[0]);
        console.log(arr2[1]);
    }

Comment: теперь появился другой вопрос как получить значения полей _id, header, text элемента массива?

Comment: Что Вы делаете? Зачем Вы делаете `JSON.stringify(el)`?

Comment: JSON.stringify(el) - преобразует Ваш JSON в строку, из которой получить _id, header, text нельзя
Сделайте просто const arr2 = arr1.news

и уже можно будет обратиться к arr2.header и т.п.

Comment: Спасибо большое всем))))! разобрался)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как-то так:

```js
const json = {
  "news": [{
      "_id": "2",
      "header": "Заголовок 2",
      "text": "Текст 2"
    },
    {
      "_id": "1",
      "header": "Заголовок 1",
      "text": "Текст 1"
    }
  ]
};

const news = json.news.reverse().map((el) => JSON.stringify(el));
// const news = json.news.reverse(); - если нужно оставить JSON

console.log(news[1]);
console.log(news[0]);
```

Comment: А зачем `reverse()`?

Comment: Чтоб выводилось ровно так же, как запросил автор вопроса) По сути можно и без него обойтись

Answer (score 1):

Метод [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) возвращает [Promise](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) с объектом Response, у которого есть асинхронный метод [.json()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Response#Methods)

```
getNews = async () => {
  const newsData = await fetch("/news").then(result => result.json());
  newsData.forEach(el => console.log(el))
};
```